# How to pass data(dictionary) from Objective-C Controller into Swift `viewcontroller` while using bridging-header? Is there any other way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I want to send a dictionary from Objective-C Controller into Swift controller. I have tried using the keyword `@obj-c`, Public in Swift controller but couldn't access.

**Objective-C code:**

```
    vc_listing_list *swiftController = [[vc_listing_list alloc] init];

    swiftController = (vc_listing_list *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
```

Here I want to access `"selectedDirectory"` variable to send dictionary value.

**Swift Code:**

```
@objc class vc_listing_list: UIViewController {

   var selectedDirectory: Dictionary<String, String>

}
```

I expect my code in objective c controller:

```
vc_listing_list *swiftController = [[vc_listing_list alloc] init];

swiftController = (vc_listing_list *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
swiftController.selectedDirectory = someDictionary;  // this line am expecting.
```

Answer (score 0):

add `@objcMembers` to swift file

```
@objcMembers class vc_listing_list: UIViewController {

var selectedDirectory: Dictionary

}
```

if you are using storyboard then, you don't need to initialize like this

```
vc_listing_list *swiftController = [[vc_listing_list alloc] init];
```

you can directly use like this

```
  vc_listing_list * swiftController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerID"];
  swiftController.selectedDirectory = someDictionary
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:swiftController animated:YES];
```

Please try to correct your class and object naming convention also.
thanks

Comment: Thanks. I can access that variable using @objcMembers and am not using storyboard, through the code only my design.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Another way to do it would be to explicitly declare `selectedDictionary` as `@objc`. Both methods result in the Swift property being visible to Objective-C, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To access an Objective-C class from Swift you need to add it to the bridging header. The bridging header is normally named after your target name e.g. `MyApp-BridgingHeader.h`

You import any headers that you need for Swift in the bridging header:

```
#import "VCListingList.h"
```

From there you can access the class from within Swift.

```
let controller = VCListingList()
```

So for your issue you would need to expose the `selectedDirectory` in the **Header** as a property complete with bridging types of `<NSString *,NSString *>`.

It would be your choice to make it `Optional` using `nullable`. If you don't want it to be `Optional` you must initialise the property before reading it in Swift.

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface VCListingList: UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) NSDictionary<NSString *,NSString *>* selectedDictionary;

//the rest of your header stuff

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Style note: don't use lower case for class names. It makes them easy to confuse with variables. So **VCListingList** is preferred to **vc_listing_list**

You can [read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift) for more information

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways to pass data from objective c to swift class.

1) using NSUserDefault

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];

[dic addObject:@"sss" forKey:@"hi"];
[dic addObject:@"eee" forKey:@"hr"];
[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:dic forKey:@"DicKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize];
```

then get data in swift class

```
let dic = NSUserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DicKey")
```

2) Using direct create object of swift class.

```
var dic : [[String:Any]]!
```

pass dict like this

NSMutableDi

```
ctionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];
[dic addObject:@"sss" forKey:@"hi"];
[dic addObject:@"eee" forKey:@"hr"];

SwiftViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SwiftViewController"];
  SwiftViewController.dict = dict
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i got some idea to pass data from objective c into swift viewcontroller. its very useful.

Comment: Passing data between objects using `UserDefaults` is convoluted and obscure and difficult to document. Please don’t do that.